# Simple SPARQL query does not give result from turtle file

Tags: sparql

I have a ttl file which I am querying. This is a sample of two nodes that I am querying:

```
<http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/R494Vol1>
    a                       "http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/ArchivalResource" ;
    locah:accessProvidedBy  "http://natarchives.com.mt/repository/MT01" ;
    locah:dateCreatedAccumulatedEnd
            "1497" ;
    locah:dateCreatedAccumulatedStart
            "1486" ;
    locah:dateCreatedAccumulatedString
            "1486-1497" ;
    locah:level             "http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/page/level/file" ;
    <http://purl.org/dc/terms/creator>
            <http://natarchives.com.mt/author/R494Vol1_NotaryGiacomoZabbara> ;
    <http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier>
            "R494Vol1" ;
    <http://purl.org/dc/terms/language>
            "la" ;
    <http://purl.org/dc/terms/type>
            "Register" ;
```

and

```
<http://natarchives.com.mt/deed/R494Vol1-D233>
    locah:accessProvidedBy  "http://natarchives.com.mt/repository/MT01" ;
    locah:associatedWith    "constituens" , "positum" , "annuam gabellam" , "juribus" , "melite" , "festo pasce ressureccionis dominice" , "moratorie" , "converso" , "bonam" , "ponderis" , "situm" , "nobilem" , "completis" , "procuratorem magnifici" , "precario" , "civitatis melite" , "jngabellacionem" , "territorium eiusdem magnifici" , "bona" , "pecunia" , "juravit" , "gabellam juxta usum melite" , "jngabellavit" , "personam" , "augustj" , "procurator magnifici" , "crastato" , "testibus testamur" ;
    locah:associatedWith    <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3617> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/place/place727> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/place/place191> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3612> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3616> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/place/place726> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/place/place190> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3619> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3611> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3615> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3614> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3618> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/place/place728> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3610> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person3613> ;
    locah:level             "http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/page/level/item" ;
    <http://purl.org/dc/terms/date>
            "8-8-1487" ;
    <http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier>
            "R494Vol1-D233" ;
    <http://purl.org/dc/terms/isPartOf>
            "http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/R494Vol1" ;
    <http://purl.org/dc/terms/type>
            "Cabella" .
```

This is the query I am trying:

```
SELECT ?x ?reg ?regId
WHERE {
?x dcterms:date "8-8-1487".
?x dcterms:isPartOf ?reg.
?reg dcterms:identifier ?regId.
}
```

As soon as I try to get the regId the query gives no results where it is obvious from the turtle file that there is a regId. Any idea why?

Comment: According to your Turtle, you should write `?x dcterms:identifier ?regId` instead of `?reg dcterms:identifier ?regId`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Are you sure? According to the RDF data, the volume also has an identifier, so there is a path `?x -isPartOf-> ?y -identifier-> ?z` in the graph. But, `isPartOf` does not link to the volume URI and uses a literal.

Comment: `"http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/R494Vol1" ` is a string literal and not the resource URI of the volume. It has to be `<http://purl.org/dc/terms/isPartOf>
            <http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/R494Vol1> ;` .

Comment: *Every* string wrapped in double-quotes (`""`) will be treated as a string literal, not as a URI. For these to be treated as URIs, they must be wrapped in angle-brackets (`<>`) instead. I see several of these in this snippet, and I am confident there are many more in the full dataset.

Comment: @AKSW, yes, you are correct! However, my query returns something too :).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your data, the value of the `isPartOf` property is a string literal, `"http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/R494Vol1"`. A string literal is distinct from a URI. So what you're getting with your query is that `?x` matches with `<http://natarchives.com.mt/deed/R494Vol1-D233>`, `?reg` matches with `"http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/R494Vol1"`, but then `?regId` doesn't match with anything, because there is no triple with the value for `?reg` as the subject in your data (nor can there be, because subjects can't be literals in RDF).

To fix in your data, you would need to replace `"http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/R494Vol1"` with a proper URI, surrounding with angle brackets instead of quotes: `<http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/R494Vol1>`.

If it's not possible to fix your data, you can also query around it, by making SPARQL convert the literal to an IRI, for example:

```
SELECT ?x ?regIri ?regId
WHERE {
  ?x dcterms:date "8-8-1487".
  ?x dcterms:isPartOf ?reg.
  BIND(IRI(?reg) as ?regIri) 
  ?regIri dcterms:identifier ?regId.
}
```